# Grant SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW permission for Android Instrumented tests

Tags: android, android-permissions, android-testing, android-instrumentation

I'm trying to grant the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission for Instrumented tests with a `GrantPermissionRule` (from `androidx.test.rule.GrantPermissionRule` package) as follow:

```
@get:Rule var permissionRule: GrantPermissionRule = GrantPermissionRule.grant(
    android.Manifest.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW,
    android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION
)
```

This works fine for granting the `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permission for all tests but it doesn't work for `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission.

I ran my tests on a Android 8.0.0 Api 26 device.

Any idea on how to grant the `SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW` permission for Android instrumented tests?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?